# Integration of $\frac{1}{1+x^2+x^4+\cdots +x^{2m}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis

Please calculate $$A_m=\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2+x^4+\cdots +x^{2m}}$$

My idea is $$A_m=\int \frac{1-x^2}{1-x^{2m+2}}\: dx$$ so I tried to use residue theorem to upper half circle with radius $R$.
But, I cannot calculate it.

Comment: It's quite obvious that for your second integral all the poles lie on the unit circle (and are in fact, $(2m+2)$th roots of unity). Does this help?

Comment: Let $\omega = exp(i \pi /(m+1))$, then $A_n= \sum _{k=1}^{m} \frac{2\pi i}{(\omega ^k- \omega)\cdots (\omega^k - \omega ^{k-1})(\omega^k - \omega ^{k+1})\cdots (\omega^k - \omega ^m)(\omega^k - \omega ^{m+1})(\omega^k - \omega ^{m+2})\cdots (\omega^k - \omega ^{2m+1})}$ but I can't calculate more.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes the source and motivation of the problem, your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Yes. For example,$A_1=\pi$, $A_2=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$.So, what is $A_m$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The residue method is a bit cumbersome, I suggest a more elementary series approach.

HINTS:

1:$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}=\int_{-\infty}^{-1}+\int_{-1}^{1}+\int^\infty_{1}$$

2: $$\frac1{1-x^{n}}=\sum_{k\ge0}x^{nk}$$ for $|x|<1$.

3: $$\frac1{1-x^{n}}=-\sum_{k\ge0}\frac1{x^{n}}x^{-nk}$$ for $|x|>1$.

4: $$\int \sum =\sum \int$$ at most time.

5: $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac1{x-k}=\pi\cot(\pi x)$$

I will elaborate later.

I found the answer to be ($2m+2=n$):
$$A_n=\frac{2\pi}n(-\cot(\frac{3\pi}n)+\cot(\frac{\pi}n))$$

**EDIT:**

Let $f(x)=\frac{1-x^2}{1-x^{n}}=\frac1{g(x)}-\frac{x^2}{g(x)}$.
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\frac1{g(x)}dx+\int_{-1}^{1}\frac1{g(x)}dx+\int^\infty_{1}\frac1{g(x)}dx-(\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\frac{x^2}{g(x)}dx+\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{x^2}{g(x)}dx+\int^\infty_{1}\frac{x^2}{g(x)}dx)$$

The second integral equals
$$\sum_{k\ge0}\int_{-1}^{1}x^{nk}dx=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac2{nk+1}=2\sum_{k=-\infty}^0\frac1{1-nk}$$

The third integral equals
$$-\sum_{k\ge0}\int^\infty_{1}\frac1{x^{n}}x^{-nk}dx=-\sum_{k\ge1}\int^\infty_{1}x^{-nk}dx=\sum_{k\ge1}\frac1{1-nk}$$

With the map $x \mapsto -x$, It can be shown that the first and the third integrals are equal(note that $n$ is even).

So, the first three integrals combine to give
$$2\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{1-nk}=2\frac1n\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{1/n-k}=\frac{2\pi}n\cot(\pi/n)$$

For the other three integrals, with similar procedures, gives
$$2\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{3-nk}=2\frac1n\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{3/n-k}=\frac{2\pi}n\cot(3\pi/n)$$

Therefore, $$A_n=\frac{2\pi}n(\cot(\pi/n)-\cot(3\pi/n))$$

Comment: Hi, do you mind elaborating how number 3 comes about?

Comment: @J.smith You might be interested in the full solution.

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat See my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\gamma$ be the upper half circle $C$ with radius $R$ centered at $0$ and the segment from $A=(-R,0)$ to $B=(R,0)$. Clearly, inside $\gamma$, the function $f(z)=\frac{z^2-1}{z^{2m+2}-1}$ has $m$ poles $z=\omega_k\equiv=e^{\frac{\pi i k}{m+1}}=\omega_1^k$, $k=1,2,\cdots,m$ and on $AB$, $f(x)$ has two removable singular points $-1$ and $1$. For large $R$, using $\omega_k^{2m+2}=1$ and
$$ \frac{1+e^{ix}}{1-e^{ix}}=i\cot(\frac x2),$$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_\gamma f(z)\: dz&=&2\pi i\sum_{k=1}^m\text{Res}(f(z),z=\omega_k)\\
&=&2\pi i\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{\omega_k^2-1}{(2m+2)\omega_k^{2m+1}}\\
&=&\frac{\pi i}{m+1}\sum_{k=1}^m\bigg[\omega_k^{-2m+1}-\omega_k^{-2m-1}\bigg]\\
&=&\frac{\pi i}{m+1}\sum_{k=1}^m\bigg[\omega_k^{3}-\omega_k\bigg]\\
&=&\frac{\pi i}{m+1}\sum_{k=1}^m\bigg[\omega_1^{3k}-\omega_1^k\bigg]\\
&=&\frac{\pi i}{m+1}\bigg[\omega_1^3\frac{1-\omega_1^{3m}}{1-\omega_1^3}-\omega_1\frac{1-\omega_1^{m}}{1-\omega_1}\bigg]\\
&=&\frac{\pi i}{m+1}\bigg[\frac{1+\omega_1^{3}}{1-\omega_1^3}-\frac{1+\omega_1}{1-\omega_1}\bigg]\\
&=&-\frac{\pi i}{m+1}\bigg[\cot(\frac{3\pi}{2(m+1)})-\cot(\frac{\pi}{2(m+1)})\bigg].
\end{eqnarray}
On $C$,
$$\bigg|\int_C \frac{z^2-1}{z^{2m+2}-1}\: dz\bigg|\le\int_C \bigg|\frac{z^2-1}{z^{2m+2}-1}\bigg|\: |dz|\le \int_C\frac{|z|^2+1}{|z|^{2m+2}-1}\: |dz|=\frac{R^2+1}{R^{2m+2}-1}2\pi R\to 0$$
as $R\to\infty$. On $AB$
$$ \int_{-R}^Rf(z)dz=\int_{-R}^Rf(x)dx\to\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\infty)dx $$
as $R\to\infty$.
Thus
$$\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=-\frac{\pi}{m+1}\bigg[\cot(\frac{3\pi}{2(m+1)})-\cot(\frac{\pi}{2(m+1)})\bigg].$$

Comment: This is not correct. Firstly, your definition of cotangent has an extra factor of 1/2. Secondly, you forgot to divide the expression inside the cotangent function by 2. Compare yours to my answer above.

Comment: @Szeto, I made a mistake and now it is the same as yours. Thank you for pointing the error.