# Anti-symmetric Pascal triangle

Tags: combinatorics, complex-numbers, binomial-coefficients

I was (and am) curious about finding a closed form for the integral for:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2+\cdots+x^{2n}}dx$$

After some investigation, I found that:

$$1 = 1$$

$$1+x^2 = 0 + (1+x^2)$$

$$1+x^2 +x^4 = 1 - (1+x^2) + (1+x^2)^2$$

$$1+x^2 +x^4+x^6 = 0 + 2(1+x^2) - 2(1+x^2)^2 + (1+x^2)^3$$

$$1+x^2 +x^4+x^6 +x^8 = 1 - 2(1+x^2) + 4(1+x^2)^2 -3(1+x^2)^3 + (1+x^2)^4$$

If we put the coefficients of $(1+x^2)^n$ into a triangle, we produce:

\begin{matrix}
    &&&&&1\\
    &&&&0&&1\\
    &&&1&&-1&&1\\
    &&0&&2&&-2&&1\\
    &1&&-2&&4&&-3&&1\\
    \end{matrix}
(Feel free to make any corrections.)

whence it may be remarked upon that this is very similar to Pascal's triangle, except to find the entry below consecutive elements in  $x,y$ in the same row, you take $x-y$ instead of $x+y$. (This is consistent if you let all entries adjacent to the left diagonal be equal to $1$, and $0$ for the right diagonal.)

Is there a name for the triangle generated by this rule? How is it related to Pascal's triangle?

Comment: $1+x^2+...+x^{2n}$ is the sum of geometric progression.

Comment: @markvs I know. Is that relevant?

Comment: $$1+\dots+x^{2n}=\sum_{l=1}^n(\sum_{k=l}^n \binom{k}{l}(-1)^{k-l}) (x^2+1)^l $$

Comment: from geometric [rogression it can be derived that $$1+\dots+x^{2n}=\frac{-1+\sum_{0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k} (-1)^{n+1-k}(x^2+1)^k}{x^2-1}$$

Comment: @legionwhale: You want to compute the integral.  Right? This  makes it easier.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea Yep, I see that I could have saved myself some algebra. I guess the subtraction rule could follow somewhat nicely from there. If I was to add another question, is there a neat explanation for what the diagonals specifically correspond to in this triangle?

Comment: @markvs Ah, ok, this particular question was more about the triangle -- but yes. Even still, I can't (at least, not immediately) see how using the geometric sum formula makes it easier. In the case n= 1, how is the geometric formula helping you deduce the integral is $\pi$?

Comment: @markvs OEIS A239473 I think no simpler expression, but you can check its origin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integration of $\frac{1}{1+x^2+x^4+\cdots +x^{2m}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2770635/integration-of-frac11x2x4-cdots-x2m). Admittedly this is a a bit dangerous as a dupe target because that is a low quality question.

Comment: So use [ApproachZero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2Bx%5E2%2B%5Ccdots%2Bx%5E%7B2n%7D%7Ddx%24&p=1) to hunt for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is interesting is that $$I_n=\int\frac{1}{1+x^2+\cdots+x^{2n}}\,dx=\int \frac{x^2-1}{x^{2 n+2}-1}\,dx$$ write
$$I_n=x \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{2 (n+1)};1+\frac{1}{2 (n+1)};x^{2
   n+2}\right)-$$ $$\frac{1}{3} x^3 \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{3}{2 (n+1)};1+\frac{3}{2
   (n+1)};x^{2 n+2}\right)$$
So
$$J_n=\int_{-t}^{+t}\frac{1}{1+x^2+\cdots+x^{2n}}\,dx=\int_{-t}^{+t} \frac{x^2-1}{x^{2 n+2}-1}\,dx$$ is
$$J_n=2 t \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{2 (n+1)};1+\frac{1}{2 (n+1)};t^{2
   n+2}\right)-$$ $$\frac{2}{3} t^3 \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{3}{2 (n+1)};1+\frac{3}{2
   (n+1)};t^{2 n+2}\right)$$

Now, for $t\to \infty$, have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092190/asymptotics-of-hypergeometric-2f-1abcz-for-large-z-to-infty). However, the problem is not so simple since the last argument also involves $n$.

For some specific values of $n$, I have been able to produce some explicit values for infinite values of $t$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n &  \frac 1 \pi I_n \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\
 3 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 4 & \frac{1}{5} \sqrt{10-2 \sqrt{5}} \\
 5 & \frac{1}{6} \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)\\
7 & \frac{1}{4} \left(1+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}\right)\\
 9 & \frac{1}{10} \left(2+\sqrt{10-2 \sqrt{5}}\right) \\
11 & \frac{1}{12} \left(1+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{6}\right) \\
 14 & \frac{1}{15} \sqrt{13+5 \sqrt{5}+\sqrt{150+66 \sqrt{5}}}
\end{array}
\right)$$
The ones which are missing correspond to non explicit roots of polynomials of $n$.

Totally empirical (based on a quick and dirty regression for $1 \leq n \leq 100$ (with $R^2=0.999977$)

$$\frac n \pi  I_n \sim  \frac{577}{5184}+\frac{885 }{2092}n$$  For $n=200$, this correlation gives a value of $1.3308$ to be compared to the exact $1.3334$.

Comment: Quite impressive. It would be nicer if you put down the way to get the hypergeometric expression.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea. Just as you would do but I simplified the result . Have a look at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B%28x%5E2-1%29%2F%28x%5E%282n%2B2%29-1%29%2Cx%5D